# Hook Mechanic and syncing Time.Delta Time C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am tackling a new project where one of my core mechanics is a hook where if an object is hit they are either pulled or destroyed.

For now I am just trying to get this movement mechanic working, 
Here is my code:

```
public class Hook : MonoBehaviour
{ //Remember Couroutine is pretty much update()

public Transform Target;
private float Thrust; // Int for motion
public Rigidbody rb;
public float HookTravelTime = 5f; //Define float for seconds
private bool moving = false;  //Are we currently moving?
public int time; 


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Thrust = 75f;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    print("working");
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "enemy")
    {
        print("xd");
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}


void ThrowHook()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H) && !moving)
    {
        moving = true;
        var moveIncrement = new Vector3(Thrust, 0, 0 * Time.deltaTime); // setting values? difference between var and int?

        while (time <= HookTravelTime)
        {
            time = Time.deltaTime + 1;// I want the int time to increase by 1 every "second". Cannot impicitly convert type float to iny. An explicit conversion exists.???

            // How do I put VAR MOVEINCREMENT into here? I still don't understand what a var is. Why can't I just make a void()
        }

        if (time >= HookTravelTime)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.position, Thrust); // return to empty object which is in front of player.
        }

    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
    {
        ThrowHook();
    }
}
```

The problems are what I have annotated in the code, nonetheless I will go through them.

In Void ThrowHook(), I am trying to reduce the Int(time) to +1 for every second that has passed in the game. I have tried to sync this with Time.Delta Time but this however does not work. I have no idea what I am doing here.

Just above the while loop in ThrowHook(), I have been told to create a var to store information in it( Var MoveIncrement). I have tried to put the constant movement code in it but I have no idea how to call it. If possible could you tell me if this line of code is wrong

Please ignore the Bool Moving for now as I again have not been consistent trying to figure this problem out.

Hopefully I have made these problems clear, I am sorry if they are not, I am in a rush to go to rugby practice.

TLDR: I want a hook to have a constant force forward while the "time" has not passed 5 seconds yet. If it has, then the hook moves back to a target position in front of the player.

Thank you :P

Comment: The Q&A nature of Stack Overflow doesn't lend itself to posting multiple distinct questions, even if they are about the same part or section of the code. I suggest you focus on one problem at a time and reduce your question to only deal with that, otherwise, you risk getting 2-3 answers, each of them correct, but you're still forced to "Accept" only one of them. Also, if you're really looking for a discussion on how to do the things you're dealing with, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to be, and a chat or discussion forum is more appropriate.

Comment: Got it, was in a hurry so it went right through me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time.deltaTime` is the time in seconds it took to complete the last frame, so if your game is running at 60fps its value will be 1/60. You'll probably use it always since in the duration of frames isn't constant so try to understand it very well
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

That said, if you want to wait for 5 seconds to do something using Update():

```
float hookTravelTime=5f; // you can use an int if you want full seconds only, you will be able to compare float>int/float<int/ecc
float timeHookTraveling=0f; //in your case the variable named "time"(it isn't a good variable name)

bool isHookActive=false;
    void Update()
    {
//here you should check your input foor hook activation
/*
if(keyPressed...)
{
    what the hook should do on actiovation code here
    isHookActive=true;
    }
*/

//if the hook is not resting execute the code below
      if(isHookActive)
       {
//if the hook traveled for more than hookTravelTime(5 seconds in your case)
         if(timeHookTraveling>=hookTravelTime)
           {
             //your action after the 5 seconds of hook travel
             timeHookTraveling=0f;//reset the travel time for your next hook activation
             isHookActive=false;//reset this bool so your Update will not check this script until you don't activate it in your ThrowHook.
           }
//if the hook didn't travel for at least 5 seconds, increase its travel time by frame's time, thisone will be executed until you reach value 5.0f
         else//or without else, whatever
           {
             timeHookTraveling+=Time.deltaTime;//increase your travel time by last frame's time
           }
       }
    }
```

you have problems because your are casting to int a very little fraction (as i said before something near 1/60 if you are at 60fps) so its value will always be 0

Extra: don't check the input that way, try to add some logic in functions: if(input) then throw(so check the input then decide to call throw)
Also i would suggest you to not access enemy by its name, if you are going to use a prefab your enemy's name will be "enemy(clone)", what if will have more enemies, ecc? use a layer, a tag or something similar.

Comment: Where do you activate for isHookActive to be true? This is in the first If statement. I also do not understand the area where it says //your action after the 5 seconds. Timehooktraveling is 0 and is not going up with time. Delta. When does time hooktravelling reach 5?   What purpose does the else statement have? Is it when the hook is resting?? Sorry If I am too in your face, I am just really confused :p

Comment: Where do you activate for isHookActive to be true?-you will do it whenever you throw hook(i supose you will do it when input pressed)

Timehooktraveling is 0 and is not going up with time.Delta.- it does here:
 timeHookTraveling+=Time.deltaTime;

When does time hooktravelling reach 5?-here : timeHookTraveling>=hookTravelTime don't you agree?
the hook is resting all the time unless you enter this statement: if(isHookActive)

Comment: I see you have problems with simple code :), i will add some comments on my answer, hope it will help

Comment: Thank you for understanding and re-annotating your answer! You made it very clear to me :)